# mprotect(addr, size, PROT_NONE) for guard pages and its memory consumption

Tags: linux, memory-management

I allocated some memory using [memalign](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), and I set the last page as a guard page using `mprotec(adde, size, PROT_NONE)`, so this page is inaccessible.

Does the inaccessible page consume physical memory? In my opinion, the kernel can offline the physical pages safely, right?

I also tried [madvise(MADV_SOFT_OFFLINE)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) to manually offline the physical memory but the function always fails.

Can anybody tell me the internal behavior of kernel with `mprotect(PROT_NONE)`, and how to offline the physical memory to save physical memory consumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux applications are using [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Only the kernel is managing physical RAM. Application code don't see the physical RAM.

A segment protected with `mprotect` & `PROT_NONE` won't consume any RAM.

You should allocate your segment with [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (maybe you want `MAP_NORESERVE`). Mixing `memalign` with `mprotect` may probably break libc invariants.

Read carefully [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) man page. `MADV_SOFT_OFFLINE` may require a specially configured kernel.